# RxJava using zip to chain multiple calls

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to construct an observable from a chain of API calls but I can't get it to work. What I have is four API calls `ApiA`, `ApiB`, `ApiC` and `ApiD` that return Observables using `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory`. `ApiA` and `ApiB` have to be called first and then after both are executed ApiC and ApiD should be called. After last two are executed View is initialized. I'm using zip operator for waiting to calls to finish, I'm not sure that's the way to go but I'm quite new to `RxJava` so if there is another and better way to do that please let me know. 
Below is my code with comments showing where I got stuck

```
public Observable syncData() {
    return Observable.zip(
        // these two calls are executed
        callApiA(),
        callApiB(),
        (o, o2) -> Observable.zip(
            /* these two calls are not executed, it seems as if this zip has 
            no subscriber but i don't know why ... */
            callApiC(),
            callApiD(),
            (o, o2) -> {
                someLogic();
                return Observable.empty();
            }));
}
```

And in view I just subsribe to this method

```
viewModel.syncData().subscribe(
            o -> mainAdapter.update(),
            throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace()
);
```

Again I'm fairly new to RxJava so any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the calls are not running on the main thread? You can add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` on `callApiX()` for that. Do you have some log?

Comment: all calls are on Schedulers.io() and there's no error or warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track.

However, be aware that the `.zip` last parameter, `Func` is not returning `Observable<R>` from it's `call` function, but `R` directly.

So you are returning `Observable` to the `Subscriber`'s `onNext` and not it's event.

`flatMap` in between is needed:

```
Observable.zip(callApi1(), callApi2(), Pair::new)
     .flatMap((pair) -> Observable.zip(
           Observable.just(pair.first()),
           Observable.just(pair.second()),
           callApiC(),
           callApiD(),
           (t1, t2, t3, t4) -> {
                 someLogic()
           }));
```

This is pseudocode, however I hope you get the idea:

1. `Zip` first 2 calls (A, B)
2. Return a `Pair` of objects returned from those functions
3. Transform `Pair` using `zip` operator (using `flatMap` operator)
4. Compose this `Pair` with the next 2 calls (C,D)
5. Returns composed objects from `someLogic()` function (remembering, that `someLogic` should return `R` and not `Observable<R>`)

**Hint for future:**
Try writing it without lambda expressions first. Then you can see input and output parameters, so it is easier to write code. Then rewrite the same with lambda expressions.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'm still stuck in same place, first two calls are executed and then nothing

Comment: Great! that's what I was looking for, I was first returning an observable directly, then using flatMap solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The important part is that Observables are not executed until they are subscribed to.

So to explain what is happening the first `Observable.zip` is given a combination function `(callApiA(),callApiB()) -> Observable<Something>`, so it produces an `Observable<Observable<Something>>`.
The observable is sent as an element and never subscribed to.

To fix it you will need to flatten the observable stream: `Observable.zip(...).flatmap(s -> s)`. This flattens the stream to `Observable<Something>` and subscribes to the inner observable.